# Explain res = id^(id >>> 32), please

Tags: java, oop, hash

Hullo!
I have this code

```
public int hashCode(){
        int res = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        res = 31 * res + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return res;
    }
```

And this is my equals code

```
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // object ref identical or not
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        //class identical?
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;

        if(id != person.id) return false;

        return Objects.equals(name, person.name);
    }
```

I don`t understand operations over result.
Why do we have to do these operations?
Will be very grateful if someone can explain it to me

Equals i understand well, but i read they are connected somehow, so I've attached the comparison code just in case

Comment: Are you asking why someone wrote `equals` and `hashCode` methods in that class?

Comment: Don't think about it too hard. The only thing a hash function has to do is `A==B => h(A)==h(B)`, which this obviously does. Then there is `A!=B => h(A)!=h(B) "as often as you can manage"` which makes it fast. Violating the second nice-to-have rule will still result in a working hash (albeit a slower one). Try a hashCode that returns 0 for everything. Things should still work.

Comment: But to your question, if `id` is `int`, `^ >>>` does nothing. If it is `long`, it xors its two 32-bit halves together.

Comment: assuming `id` is a `long`,  this is just calculating its hashcode in the same way as done by  [`Long.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode())

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Explain res = id^(id >>> 32) please

- `id >>> n` for an int, shifts id right `n%32` bits without extending the negative sign bit if one is present.  So `(id >>> 32)` is effectively == id.
- `^` is an exclusive OR which says for any bit `a` and `b`, `a^b == 1` if `a and b` are different otherwise they `a^b == 0`.  E.g. `1^1 == 0.  0^0 == 0, 1^0 == 1`

So `id ^ id == 0`.

if `id` is a long, `(id >>> 32)` shifts the high order `32 bits` of that long `right 32 bits` and then `exclusive ors` the original long with that value.

The over all computation of hashCode is to use that technique sometimes employed with others to generate a number for use in data structures that are used to index by hashcode.  in Java, primary examples are `Maps` and `Sets`.

Here is a demo.

```
long v = Long.MIN_VALUE; // has 1 in hob (high order bit) and rest is 0's
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(v));
 
long result = v ^ (v >>> 32); // now hob should be 1 and hob of low order int should be 1

System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(result));
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: ... so, if `id` is a long, it is combining all 64 bits in a 32 bit `int` ...

Comment: Not quite. If id is a long, `id >>> 32` will move the high order `int` to the low order position with 32 0's now in the high order position. Then the original id will be exclusive or'd with that resulting in a new long.  The overall contents are determined by the original contents of course.

Comment: @user22471702 I modified my answer to provide a demo of my comment.